# Sending file to dropbox from android

Tags: android, dropbox

i am doing work on drop box through android, i need create a folder and send a file(Eg: .txt file) to that folder from SD card of the mobile.. I can successfully create folders using the following statement

```
 Entry entry = api.createFolder("dropbox", "test_folder");
```

how can i send file from SD card to dropbox folder, i have searched in https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs

but i didnt find the right solution yet, please give me the solution to send file to folder in dropbox.

Please help me, thanks in advance....

Comment: /fileops/copy is right above /fileops/create_folder in the documentation. Do you have some code and perhaps error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you would like to use the Android-Api and have a look at

```
public int putFile(String root, String dbPath, File localFile)
```

and

```
 public File getFile(String root, String dbPath, File localFile, String etag)
```

I think it's usage is straight-forward.

Comment: how should i give the localfile name,can i place directly local file path there? please tell me

Comment: You need to pass a File-object. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

Comment: It is a http-etag, used for caching. You can pass null.

Comment: but getFile() showing java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed, how can solve it